# Google Cloud auto-scaling thrashes between 0 and 1, even with minimum of 1

Tags: google-compute-engine, autoscaling

I have a managed instance group with auto scaling enabled. I have a minimum of 1 and maximum of 10 with health checks and cpu 0.8

The number of instances continually switches between 0 and 1. Every few minutes. I am unable to find the reason GCP decides to remove an instance and then immediately add it back. Health checks have no logs anywhere.

More concerning is that the minimum instances required is violated.

Thoughts? Thanks!

**Edit**: This may be due to instances becoming unhealthy, most likely because a firewall rule was needed to allow health checks on the instances. The health check worked for load balancing, but not instance health it seems. I'm using a custom network, so I needed to add the firewall rule.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks#configure_a_firewall_rule_to_allow_health_checking

Will confirm/update after some monitoring time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be confused between two different features: the autohealer and
the autoscaling of Managed Instance Groups.

- The `--min-num-replicas` is a parameter of the autoscaler, setting this parameter you are sure that the target number of instances will never be set below a certain threshold. However the autohealing works on its own not following the configuration of the autoscaling.

Therefore when instances belong to a managed group and fail health checks, they are considered dead instances and removed from the pool if autohealing is enabled without taking into account the minimum number of replicas.

It is always best practise to verify that [health checks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances#monitoring_groups) are working properly in order to avoid this kind of misbehaviour. The common issues are:

- Firewall rules
- Wrong protocols/ports
- Server not starting automatically at the powerup of the machine

Notice also that if the health checks are a bit more complex and interact with some kind of software you need to be sure that the instance is started before configuring accordingly [initial delay flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instance-groups/managed/set-autohealing), i.e. the length of the period during which the instance is known to be initializing and should not be autohealed even if unhealthy.